# What does the error I/zygote (11430) mean?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I'm aware that zygote is a special application process that handles forking (thanks to another question), however I have not been able to find out what the specific error '11430' means. I am working on a project for the Angela Yu Flutter course, and have been unable to get any output in the console other than this message, even though my code mirrors hers.

This is what my console looks like:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Waiting for Android SDK built for x86 to report its views...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64735/QY3N9RVY76A=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/zygote  (11430): Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=22KB
I/zygote  (11430): After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=22KB
I/zygote  (11430): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

Comment: I don't think its error. I believe, it is only message from flutter. Coming to your output, I think there is something else to be checked.

Comment: Any idea what that could be?